# parallelism configuration in trident topology (storm)

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka, trident

After reading [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2012/10/16/understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-storm-topology/) and [this](http://www.datasalt.com/2013/04/an-storms-trident-api-overview/) I'm having difficulties understanding how to configure my trident topology.

Basically my storm application is reading from [kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/projects.html), doing some data manipulations and finally writing to [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

Here is how I'm currently building my topology:

```
private static StormTopology buildTopology() {
// connection to kafka
ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts(broker_zk, broker_path);
TridentKafkaConfig kafkaConfig = new TridentKafkaConfig(zkHosts, topic);
kafkaConfig.scheme = new RawMultiScheme();
StateFactoryFields[] cassandraStateFactories = createStateFactories();
TransactionalTridentKafkaSpout spout = new TransactionalTridentKafkaSpout(kafkaConfig);
TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();
Stream kafkaSpout = topology.newStream("kafkaspout", spout).parallelismHint(1).shuffle();
Stream filterValidatStream = kafkaSpout.each(new Fields("bytes"), new SplitKafkaInput(), EventData.getEventDataFields()).parallelismHint(1);
for (StateFactoryFields stateFactoryFields : cassandraStateFactories) {
    filterValidatStream.groupBy(stateFactoryFields.groupingFields)
        .persistentAggregate(stateFactoryFields.cassandraStateFactor, new Count(), new Fields("count")).parallelismHint(2);
}
logger.info("Building topology");
return topology.build();
}
```

So I got a spout and a few operations (filter, grouopBy) with parallelismHint.
I don't understant hor to determine the optimal parallelismHint, moreover if I'm setting this value in my code, how does it work in conjunction with storm standard topology configurations such as

```
topology.max.task.parallelism
topology.workers
topology.acker.executors
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent [gist by mrflip here](https://gist.github.com/mrflip/5958028) that attempts to outline how to tune a storm/trident topology. This should guide you in selecting your parameters (both the ones you have suggested in your question and others you may not have thought of yet).

Comment: Looking good in first sight. I will go deeper into it and update, thanks

Comment: I cannot open that page, could you please give me another accessible one? Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi @Yohn it should be publicly accessible.

Comment: OK, I got it. There must be something wrong with my LAN. Thanks all the same.